# Is there any tool for automatically generate java classes with annotation style in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I just have the db schema, and want to get the corresponding java classes for them in hibernate, and I do not want the hbm xml file style, so want to get the java classes with annotation generated automatically, is there any tool for this job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reverse engineering module of [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) for Eclipse and Ant can generate Java classes using EJB annotations. Can also be used from Maven (see the [Hibernate3 Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/)).

NetBeans also has a [reverse engineering module](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ReverseEngineering) for Hibernate (that leverages the above one I believe).